# Allow users to uploading videos to vimeo

Tags: 7, media, files

I am totally new at making websites using Drupal. I started on Monday (April 1st) and I've been using drupal.org and drupalize.me to start learning and building some basic stuff.
There is one thing I want to do and I've been stuck for 2 days now.

I want to be allow the users of my site to upload videos which will get stored inside my database and, using the data from my database, upload it to Vimeo site and use vimeo player as the player.

This is my goal right now but I am stuck on the very first step TnT. 
I have the module "Media-7.x-1.3" installed on my site and tried using it to upload videos. I know this only allows me to upload videos from the admin end when you are creating a new content and you have to edit the "article" or "blog" post that contains the video file if you want to change something and doesn't allow the users of my site to upload the videos directly but I just wanted to get started on something.

So I followed the instructions and went to 
- Structure -> Content Types -> Add content type -> name the content type (video files) -> save and add fields (everything else is left as default) -> add new field (upload videos) -> field type = file -> widget = media file selector -> save -> upload destination = public files (there are no other options for me to choose) -> save

this will bring me to manage fields page
label = upload videos -> allowed file extensions for uploaded files = mp3, mp4, wmv, jpg (i gave it bunch of random extensions so I can test it if it works or not) -> maximum upload size = 50 MB -> every other fields are left as default -> save

inside manage display page
upload videos format = rendered file -> save

after all the configurations, I go to 
Add content -> video files -> title = videos -> click on "Select media" at the bottom -> Browse -> select my video file I want to upload (mp4 file, 34 MB) -> Submit 
and nothing happens. no error message, no video uploaded or anything. I'm just stuck in the upload overlay page and I would have to hit cancel to get out of the page.

but if I try to upload a image file (jpg file that I allowed earlier), I can see the preview of my image and gives me an option to "Select media" or "Remove media" (the upload overlay page is gone of course).

So I have no idea why it's not working for video files or what is going on. AND this is not even what I want to do...sigh...

Please help me TnT

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe uploading directly to Vimeo is a supported feature. I do see an unmaintained module that claims to do something similar, though: http://drupal.org/project/mm_vimeo

I haven't looked at the code, but you could write a module to accomplish the following:

1. Use a regular file upload field for videos. Nothing fancy. Use the Media module to enable URL video embedding (as if we've copied/pasted a Vimeo URL directly).
2. Create a cron job to keep an eye on nodes created/updated of that type, making note of videos that should be uploaded to Vimeo.
3. Upload videos to Vimeo (see: http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods#vimeo-videos-upload)
4. Modify the Video nodes to include a Vimeo URL to embed in the player.
5. Remove the file upload, chances are it's huge and not worth retaining.

I've used a modified approach with this in the past with transcoding services in conjunction with Amazon S3 storage and Cloudfront CDN hosting. Very good combo.

Comment: thanks for the reply and giving me a guide to where to start. I'll try this out. you da man!

Comment: Yes, this is definitely more of an advanced use case that we cannot try and provide support for. You could possibly file this as a feature request for the Media: Vimeo module.

Answer (score 1):

I`m actually working on this:

Use this module for vimeoapi oauth2 integration:

[vimeoapi](https://www.drupal.org/project/vimeoapi)

media_vimeo_upload: it sends the media video upload by the user (file) to vimeo and change the drupal file to a vimeo url on the media file. This is a sandbox code but is useful for the moment.

[media_vimeo_upload](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/gedur/233402)

Check that for the moment your filename should be or change the code (this will be configured by UI on future commits):

```
$fieldnames = array(
  'field_media_video',
);
```

As both modules work are in progress, help and patches are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this [Vimeo Video Uploader](https://www.drupal.org/project/vimeo_video_uploader) module, Its has feature related as you expect.

> A Module for integrating Vimeo APIs with Drupal. Installing the module creates two fields in selected content type which will be used to upload Video to Vimeo. This module uses [Video Embed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) for embedding video URL after video is uploaded.